# How do I convert an object to a custom string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I want to overload the conversion of an object to a string, so that the following example would output the string "TEST" instead of "[object Object]". How do I do this?

```
function TestObj()
{
    this.sValue = "TEST";
}
function Test()
{
    var x = new TestObj();
    document.write(x);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should overload the `toString` method ...

```
TestObj.prototype.toString = function(){return this.sValue;}
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/Ktp9E/

Answer (score 12):

You need to override the toString() function that all objects have.  Try

```
TestObj.prototype.toString = function() {return this.sValue };
```